# Get the point coordinates of a CombinedGeometry

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using the code below to exclude one geometry from a `CombinedGeometry`

[image]

and get the final geometry as below:

[image]

I was wondering is there a way to get the geometry definition of this final result? Something like a point collection or something like that that helps me redraw this with different properties later or even write the point coordinates to a file?

```
<Window x:Class="Combine.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas Width="300" Height="300">
        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Transparent">
            <Path.Data>

                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="40,40, 200, 50" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="100,0, 50, 200" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `combinedGeometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();` method. This will return a PathGeometry object. You can then either convert it to string and write to file, either run through the figurs that are contained in the PathGeometry and use the coordinates.

```
PathGeometry geometry = combinedGeometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

Console.WriteLine(geometry.ToString());


foreach (PathFigure figure in geometry.Figures)
{
     Console.WriteLine(figure.StartPoint);
     foreach (PathSegment segment in figure.Segments)
     {
         foreach (Point point in ((PolyLineSegment)segment).Points)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(point);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use PathGeometry.Combine() instead of the CombinedGeometry. The resulting PathGeometry has figures and segments. PS: You can also create a PathGeometry from any other geometry. Have a look at the static constructor PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry().
    PathGeometry result = PathGeometry.Combine(g1, g2, GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, null);